# Error on POST request with Jersey to API, works fine with POSTMAN

Tags: java, json, post, request, jersey

I developed an API RESTful service (backend) with Laravel 5, and I tested it with POSTMAN. There are several resources to get information with GET and POST requests, they work fine with POSTMAN. I started to test the API with a Java Client with Jersey. The GET methods work fine with code like this, and the response is a json, which I parse with Jackson.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(ClientUrl);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = 
webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
Response mResponse = invocationBuilder.get();
```

The next method I want to test is the login, with POST method. 
With POSTMAN I use in the header the key "Content-Type" +  value "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and in the body I send a Json with this information

```
{"email":"xxxxxx@gmail.com", "password":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

To use the POST method with Jersey I use the next code

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Form mForm = new Form();
mForm.param("email", email);
mForm.param("password", password);

WebTarget target = client.target(Utils.URL_LOGIN);
//As stated in the documentation, the APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED = 
//"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Builder request = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
//I print the request to verify the request 
print(request.toString());
Response response =  request.post(Entity.form(mForm));
//I print the response to verify the response received and also the code 
print("Response: " + response.toString());
print("Code: " + response.getStatus());
String result = response.readEntity(String.class);
response.close();
print(result);
```

When I print the request.toString() I get this

```
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder@65e579dc
```

When the response is printed

```
Response: InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://www.dance-world.com/api/login, status=200, reason=OK}}
```

The status received is 200, but when I print the response.readEntity I get the response that I use in the backend for thoses cases when the server doesn't receive information with the request.

```
{"code":400,"status":"error","message":"No data attached to the request"}
```

When I use POSTMAN and the result is 200, with success I receive the Token as a String.

I can't figure what's my error, because I'm following the code in documentation and with the book RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0

Comment: '*I use in the header the key "Content-Type" + value "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and in the body I send a Json*'. Why? This content type is wrong for JSON.

Comment: Lutz Horn, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I developed the backend based on a course of Laravel, in that course the functions have the next definition

```
 public function getByCountry(Request $request) {
        //Recoger los datos por post
        $json = $request->input('json', null);
        $params = json_decode($json);
        $params_array = json_decode($json, true);
        ...
}
```

And the backend requires a x-www-urlencoded, in POSTMAN I was sending the request in that format [(POST Request {x-www-urlencoded} with Postman)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h29O.png). So, when I tried to make a POST request with JSON, using Jersey or Unirest the request haven't the required format, that's the reason I had the message configured for thoses cases when the backend doesn't receive information with te request. [This is the POSTMAN request with raw Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUnxh.png) and [this is the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQmJv.png) from the backend, which says that no data was received.

The way I solved it to accept json for the requests was change the code in the backend with the next structure:

```
public function TestForPost(Request $request) {
    //Verify if the $request is a json
    $input = $request->json()->all(); //read json in request
    if (!empty($input)) {
    ...
}
```

With this change I cand send a request with Json and the backend accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried also with Unirest, because is easier to use than Jersey. I typed the code below

```
 try {
      HttpRequestWithBody requestwithBody = Unirest.post(url)
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .header("accept", "application/json");

      RequestBodyEntity requestBodyEntity = requestwithBody.body(input);

      response = requestBodyEntity.asJson();

} catch (UnirestException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    print("Status: " + String.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
    print("Body: " + String.valueOf(response.getBody()));
}
```

The local server isn't receiving the json body and I received the same response from the server

```
{"code":400,"status":"error","message":"No data attached to the request"}
```

Comment: I tried also with curl to Test the connection with the API: `curl -d '{"email":"xxxxxxx@gmail.com","password":"xxxxx"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://www.dance-world.com/api/login`

But the result is the same ` {"code":400,"status":"error","message":"No data attached to the request"}`